# What is the expression of the state after $n$ parallel hadamard gate on $n$ $\left|1\right>$ qubits?

Tags: quantum-information

The state after $n$ parallel hadamard gate on $n$ $\left|0\right>$ qubits is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{x}\left|x\right>$. I am looking for a similar expression for $n$ $\left|1\right>$ qubits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

The state you get after applying $n$ Hadamard gates on $|1 \rangle$ is
$$\left( \dfrac{|0 \rangle - |1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \right)^{\otimes n} \, .$$
This can be written as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{x}  (-1)^{\mathcal{1}.x}  |x\rangle$$
where $\mathcal{1}$ is the binary string of $n$ ones. The ${1}.x$ term in the exponent represents the bitwise inner product. For a general state labelled by  $|z \rangle$, the $n$ Hadamard gates produces the output

$$ H^{\otimes n} |z\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{x}  (-1)^{\mathcal{z}.x}  |x\rangle$$

The expressions are taken from Nielson and Chuang's book, from the section on the Deutsch - Jozsa algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a very similar superposition, except that the states with an odd number of 1s will be negated. The signs of the amplitudes for each state, in order, will follow the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence).

$$H \left| 111...1 \right\rangle = \sqrt{2^{-n}}\sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} \left| k\right\rangle (-1)^{\text{count_1_bits}(k)}$$

More generally, when you Hadamard-transform the state $\left|a\right\rangle$ with bits $\left|a\right\rangle = \left| a_1 a_2 ... a_n \right\rangle$ you end up in the state $\left|h\right\rangle = H\left|a\right\rangle = \sqrt{2^{-n}} \sum_{h_1,...,h_n}^{\{0,1\}} \left| h_0 h_1 h_2 ... h_n \right\rangle (-1)^{a_1 h_1 + a_2 h_2 + ... + a_n h_n}$. The sign of the output state is negative if number of one-bits common to both the input state and output state is odd.

The [wikipedia article on the Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform) has a diagram of the matrix the operation corresponds to, and the columns of that matrix tell you the output signs you'll end up with. If you squint your eyes you might see hints of a [familiar shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle)...

[image: Hadamard matrix looks like sierpinsky triangle]

(The Hadamard matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1&-1 \end{bmatrix}^{\otimes n}$ whereas the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}^{\otimes n}$ is exactly a Sierpinski triangle (in the limit). Those two matrices have their different element in the same place, so big Hadamard matrices end up looking like a bunch of distorted/overlayed copies of the Sierpinski triangle.)